# Fit non-linear customised model

Tags: r, linear-regression, ggplot2

I have a `data.frame` that have two cols, $x=mz$ and $y=res$. There are about ~2 million rows in the DF. When I plot the graph I get the below.[image: Scatterplot]

What I'd like to do is find a way to define two quadratics to fit to get the two curves badly sketched in orange. it would be nice to be able to do it in ggplot. I have tried to fit a stat_smooth but I haven't been able to come close to the result I want.

```
plot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(mz, res)) + geom_point()
plot + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x^-2) - x)
```

[image]
Apologies if this is something really trivial and obvious, but I am not a data scientist and I am just trying to help a friend.

Answer (score 1):

You could try quantile regression using a "generalised additive" model. With `R` you could [use the `qgam` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qgam/vignettes/qgam.html), I guess. What you need to do is to estimate a model for upper/lower values of the distribution. The figure below shows a plot from the `qgam` vignette linked above.

[image]